# Setting different prices for different store or website?

Tags: multistore, pricing

We are currently running a one domain, one website, one store, several store views  (languages) magento install.

We are looking into setting up another domain to handle a more localized market with different prices.

So I went into the backend and first set up a new store as well as two new store views for it. I choose the same root cat. for this one.

I find that it is not possible to select the store in the scope drop down in order to edit products. So I can not change product prices based on the store only based on store views.

I want all store views under the new store to have the same price without assigning it twice for each product.

Second I went to add a new website in the backend, created a new store for it as well as a new store view. I was hoping to be able to edit prices under the website scope, but this does also not work as one is again able only to select a store view.

I might have overlooked something here. How am I to set different prices for seperate stores OR websites?

**Update**: So I have added a new root category to the new website store and added a product to it to test it out. I have assigned this product to both the main website store as well as the new website store.
When I go to edit view of this product and try to choose the website in the scoope selector I am not able to select website. It will only let me select a
store view instead.

We are using Magento 1.9.0.1

The bottom line is I am able to set prices for each store view under each website. But it is not possible to set a price for a website including all store views under it. This would mean that for each product on the new website we would have to set the price twice once for each store view as the new website will have two languages.

Can someone confirm if this is the way it is supposed to work or have I gone
wrong here?

Comment: There is one entity in between t you're missing, it's the store. That can have a different root catalog and thus different prices, but it really is a different catalog, so you need to enter products twice. Or use one of the store view price extensions out there. Another approach is using catalog price rules.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was looking to use the same root catalog though.

Comment: That's option two and three in my comment. I've seen a few extensions that claim to do this at a high cost (performance, subtle bugs etc). So be warned. Catalog price rules really is the simplest approach especially if you can express large parts of the catalog price difference in percentages.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set price per website basis.

you need to go to **System->Configuration->Catalog.**

Then in the tab "Price", set **Catalog Price Scope** to "Website" instead of global.

Comment: Thank you. I have done that, but still can only set the scope selector to store views not to a whole website.

Comment: I got it now :-)

Comment: Hi, can I set inventory base on store view? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can just set the price for all store views belonging to that website, especially to set up different prices for same products per store view of each store. It means that if your store has many store views, you can absolutely set up various prices for the same product for each store view.

For example, if there are two store views in a store: English and Germany and you want to sell a product at two prices with its own store view currency such as £20 and €35 respectively. Magento default cannot allow you to do this thing at all. Therefore, if you want to do this one, you can use an extension like Multiple store view pricing I used to find on Magento Connect

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multistore-pricing-extension.html

It seems that it can also helps to set up base currency for each store view to replace for default currency as US Dollars of Magento.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found that it is possible to set the price per website. 
I just got a little confused as the selector (upper left corner) did not allow
for selecting the website level but only the store view level. So I tried out
a few things and found that if one wishes to set the price on website level one
has to select one language (store view) of that website in order to set the price. 
The price is then set for all store views belonging to that website.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- Set Price globally
- Set Price per website (you then can have different base currency and setup specific price in the currency rather than use the currency converter)

But even if you choose in **System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Price Scope => Website**

you still can't select the website scope in the admin product, so this can be considered as a UI bug.

Anyway if you choose any of the store view below, prices will be updated in every store view of the current website scope.

Answer (score 0):

I use Magmi. There is a way for setting in both ecommerce (ita and eng) same price?

If i select

[image]

Global

the ecommerce set

[image]

it's correct?

Ale