# Different prices for different store views

Tags: price, multistore, store-view

I've been looking into this alot to try figure out what is going on.

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-price-scope.html

This page on Magento docs says

`Different factors can affect the price of the same product in one location and not another. For example, there might be additional costs to bring the product to market, and other considerations that impact the price of products sold in a specific store. The following illustration shows a multisite installation with the base currency set to the website level. In each store, the same product has a different price`

My current setup has 1 website, inside this I have two stores €+£ and a corresponding store view for each €+£ again. My base currency is £ but both currencies are allowed in both store views. My Catalog Price Scope is set to Website, not Global.

According to the documentation above this should be working to set different prices for different stores but updating the price of a catalog item for one store view updates the prices for all.

I know from researching this that there is a few different paid extensions for this such as https://bsscommerce.com/magento-multiple-store-view-pricing-for-magento-2.html but I don't see why these are necessary if according to Magento docs it should just work.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to your store? Which version of Magento? When you set the price, are you in the context of your store?

Comment: @Olivier I am using Magento 2.1.11, see image attached for how I am going about trying to change the prices for different stores

Comment: This seems to be a common issue, some people say setting the price scope to website works others are depending on third party extensions https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67653/setting-different-prices-for-different-store-or-website?rq=1

Comment: I think there may be some mistakes here because if the scope of catalog price if Website, prices of a product will be the same in every store and every store view of this Website. And price of a product can be only different between Websites under a Magento Installation. This may be the reason why there is an extension like you mentioned: https://bsscommerce.com/magento-multiple-store-view-pricing-for-magento-2.html.
I see that it can help to set different prices for the same product per store/store view

Comment: @Jameslj Thanks for your comment, yeah I figured it out and made multiple websites rather than just stores or storeviews

Comment: MageAnts [multiple store view pricing](https://www.mageants.com/multi-store-view-pricing-for-magento-2.html) will solve your issues it's paid module you can check features and demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by creating different websites rather than just store views as shown here

[image]

The documentation on Magento docs was leading to the confusion because the graphic there indicates that it is done at a store level

[image]

---

Edit:

Magemnto updated graphic ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for updated graphic

Answer (score 1):

There is a FREE extension on GitHub which helps to set up different product prices (cost, regular, special prices, etc.) per store view:
https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-store-view-pricing

You can simply install via composer

```
composer require magepsycho/magento2-storepricing
```